# Using Restlet - should I return Bean Representation or String Representation?

Tags: java, restlet

Am building my RESTful API using Restlet/Jackson and following the general policy of returning the Jackon Representation of the relevant Java Bean.  For example, from the Restlet in Action book (page 108):

```
public Representation toJson() {
    ...  
    return new JacksonRepresentation<Mail>(mail);
}
```

The client app can do something like:
Mail mail = mailRep.getObject();

All works fine in both a Java web client and a Java Android client.  But what about clients built in other environments?  (e.g. a PHP client)  Can I still return the JSON representation of the Mail object as I am currently doing.  Or should I be returning the explicit Json string and letting the client figure out what to do with it?  Also would returning the string help in the future if I add information to the Mail method, but allow old clients to still work with the initial properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the two client side libraries I have used to access REST APIs (Restlet and google-http-client), both have ways of getting the JSON string from the object.
In particular Restlet's Representation has getText() and Google's HttpResponse has parseAsString().  So this all seems like a complete non-issue.  Editors - feel free to delete the question.